# In TinyXPath how to query data by indexed by element content

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xerces, tinyxpath

I am using TinyXPath to enhance an existing test tool so data from a customer XML structure can be fetched and used.

The XML looks like this

```
<Platform>
  <LinkData>
    <Plan>
      <Label>A</Label>
        <Settings>
           <SomeSetting1>ENABLED</SomeSetting1>
           <SomeSetting2>ENABLED</SomeSetting2>
        </Settings>
    </Plan>
    <Plan>
      <Label>B</Label>
        <Settings>
           <SomeSetting1>ENABLED</SomeSetting1>
           <SomeSetting2>DISABLED</SomeSetting2>
        </Settings>
    </Plan>
  </LinkData>
</Platform>
```

Given the above structure, which I have no control of, I need to be able to construct XPath expressions for TinyXPath. Put simply TinyXPath needs to return the values in the SomeSetting1/2 fields given when the correct child Label values match (resolve to true), so the test app can use them.

I have tried the following but an struggling with the way  is indexed using a child element (normally I would expect use of an attribute. Here is my attempt which does not return a result (e.g. ENABLED/DISABLED) :-

```
Platform/LinkData/Plan[child::Label='A']/Settings/SomeSetting1/text()
Platform/LinkData/Plan[child::Label='A']/Settings/SomeSetting2/text()
Platform/LinkData/Plan[child::Label='B']/Settings/SomeSetting1/text()
Platform/LinkData/Plan[child::Label='B']/Settings/SomeSetting2/text()
```

Any further help from TinyXPath gurus would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: //Settings/child::node()  (add /text() to the end if you just want the Enabled/Disabled text instead of nodes) Or are you trying to get just labels A and B?

Comment: The test must return the text values for SomeSetting1&2 firstly for the Plan 'Labelled' A and then for the Plan 'Labelled' B. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath will return what you're looking for with the given XML:

```
//Settings/child::node()/text()
```

This xpath will also add a check for Labels and group by concat `|`:

```
//LinkData/Plan[Label/text()='A']/Settings/child::node()/text() | //LinkData/Plan[Label/text()='B']/Settings/child::node()/text()
```

And this one combines them both inside the label check:

```
//LinkData/Plan[Label/text()='A' or Label/text()='B']/Settings/child::node()/text()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have been unable to get tinyxpath to return any result from the above. Although I can get //LinkData/Plan/Label/text() to work - returns A,B,C etc however adding [] into the query seems to upset it.